# Proving that if $a < b$ and $c < 0$, then $bc<ac$

Tags: inequality

Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be real numbers with $a < b$ and $c < 0$.

> Prove that $bc < ac$.

Proof: Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be real numbers with $a < b$ and $c < 0$. Since $a < b$, then $a-b < 0$.

Then I am stuck. My professor told me that I need to prove why a negative times a negative is a positive.

Answer (score 2):

$ac<bc \Rightarrow ac-bc<0 \Rightarrow c(a-b)<0$.

Now we examine the factors. $c<0$ (given) and $a<b \Rightarrow a-b<0$.

$\underbrace{c}_{<0}(\underbrace{a-b}_{<0})<0$

Both factors are negative, and since negative times negative is positive, we have

$c(a-b)>0$ or $bc<ac$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $-c\gt 0, b-a\gt 0$, we have
$$ac-bc=(-c)(b-a)\gt 0\Rightarrow ac\gt bc.$$
Here, the fact that "positive $\times$ positive is positive" is used.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $bc-ac=(b-a)c$.

The RHS has two factors: $b-a$ wich is positive (since $a<b$) and $c$ wich is negative.

This results in a negative product, so $bc-ac<0$ or equivalently $bc<ac$.

---

Underlying:

If $x>0$ and $y<0$ then $x(-y)>0$ as product of positive factors.

This with $xy+x(-y)=x(y+(-y))=x.0=0$.

Then $xy=-x(-y)<0$.

This shows that the product of a positive and negative factor yields a negative product.

Answer (score 0):

Let $d>0$, then $a+d=b \Rightarrow ca+cd=cb \Rightarrow cb-ca=cd$,

since $c<0,\ d>0 \Rightarrow cd<0 \Rightarrow cb-ca<0 \Rightarrow cb<ca$

Answer (score 0):

$c<0$ and $a-b<0$ implies that $c(a-b)>0$, why $ac>bc$.