# Prove if $x > y$ then $x \cdot z > y \cdot z$ given that $x, y, z \in \rm I\!R^+$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-writing

I'm currently following a course on voting rules and fair division, and for this we have to prove that a given social welfare ordering is scale independent. It's not really important for my question but my proof boils down to the statement below:

If $x > y$ then $x \cdot z > y \cdot z$ given that $x, y, z \in \rm I\!R^+$

This makes intuitive sense but I don't really know how to prove that properly. I am not that good at proving and I think being able to prove the above might give me some insight on how to tackle proofs in the future.

Comment: (To link the site together) The case where $z\in\mathbb{R^-}$ is covered in [Question 923799](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923799/proving-that-if-a-b-and-c-0-then-bcac).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(*) \quad xz-yz=(x-y)z$.

Since $z>0$ and $x-y>0$ , we get by $(*)$ that  $xy-xz>0$, hence $xy >xz.$

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps a lot.

Comment: I'm linking this question as a duplicate of an old, unanswered one ([Question 2469518](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2469518)), which asks the question the other way round (if $xz\geq yz$ then $x\geq y$). In that case, Fred's logic still holds.

Answer (score 1):

$x>y$ comes to the same as $x-y\in\mathbb R^+$ and $\mathbb R^+$ is closed under multiplication.

So: $$xz-yz=(x-y)z>0$$ or equivalently: $$xz>yz$$